# Different accuracy when evaluated on test_loader and entire dataset

Tags: python, numpy, torch

I built my ANN model in NumPy. In the training loop, I evaluate the model on the test dataset (MNIST from torch.datasets) - 1 loop for epochs, 1 for training, and 1 for testing (so params are already updated when model is in the test loop). Problem is that when I evaluate the model on the entire dataset (using `x = mnist_test.data.reshape(x.shape[0], -1).numpy() y = mnist_test.targets.numpy()` at once and in a loop with batches using `DataLoader()` from torch, later on, I get 2 different results. Below is the code along with results:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from torchvision import datasets
from torchvision.transforms import Compose, Normalize, ToTensor
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm

mnist_train = datasets.MNIST('.', train=True, transform=Compose([ToTensor()]), download=True)
mnist_test = datasets.MNIST('.', train=False, transform=Compose([ToTensor()]), download=True)

train_loader = DataLoader(mnist_train, batch_size=60, shuffle=True)
test_loader = DataLoader(mnist_test, batch_size=100, shuffle=False)

class BCE_Loss():
  def __init__(self):
    pass

  def __call__(self, z, y):
    if z.shape != y.shape:
      y = self.vectorize(z.shape[0], y)
    m = y.shape[1]
    return (1 / m) * np.sum(np.maximum(z, 0) - z * y + np.log(1 + np.exp(- np.abs(z))))

  def backward(self, z, y):
    if z.shape != y.shape:
      y = self.vectorize(z.shape[0], y)
    m = y.shape[1]
    self.loss = self(z, y)
    return (1 / m) * (Sigmoid()(z) - y)

  def item(self):
    return self.loss

  def vectorize(self, num_classes, y):
    """Convert scalar i to 10 dimensional vector with value 1 at i-th index. In case when mse_loss is used for classification task """

    y_vectorized = np.zeros((num_classes, y.shape[0]))
    for i, y_ in enumerate(y):
      y_vectorized[y_][i] = 1

    return y_vectorized

class Sigmoid():
  def __init__(self):
    pass

  def __call__(self, x):
    self.z_prev = x
    self.a = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

    return self.a

  def backward(self, grad):
    self.grad = grad * self.a * (1 - self.a)
    return self.grad

  def __str__(self):
    return 'activation'

class Linear():
  def __init__(self, input_size, output_size):
    self.w = np.random.randn(output_size, input_size) * np.sqrt(2 / input_size)
    self.b = np.random.randn(output_size, 1)

  def __call__(self, x):
    """x: input with shape (input_size, batch_size). Returns linear transformation x@w+b with shape (output_size, batch_size)"""
    self.prev_a = x
    self.z = self.w @ self.prev_a + self.b

    return self.z

  def backward(self, grad):
    self.grad_w = grad @ self.prev_a.T
    self.grad_b = grad.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)

    self.grad = self.w.T @ grad

    return self.grad

  def update_params(self, lr):
    self.w -= lr * self.grad_w
    self.b -= lr * self.grad_b

  def __str__(self):
    return 'linear'

np.random.seed(23)
class ANN():
  def __init__(self, layers):
    self.layers = layers

    self.num_layers = len(layers)

  def __call__(self, x):
    for layer in self.layers:
      x = layer(x)

    return x

  def backward(self, grad):
    for layer in self.layers[::-1]:
      grad = layer.backward(grad)

  def update_params(self, lr=1e-4):
    for layer in self.layers:
      if str(layer) != 'activation':
        layer.update_params(lr)


ann = ANN([
           Linear(784, 256),
           Sigmoid(),
           Linear(256, 10)
])
loss_fn = BCE_Loss()

# TRAINING
epochs = 10
train_loss = []
train_acc = []
val_loss = []
val_acc = []
lr = 3e-1
sigmoid = Sigmoid()

for epoch in range(epochs):
  running_loss = 0.
  total = 0.
  correct = 0
  for i, (x, y) in enumerate(tqdm(train_loader), 1):
    x = x.reshape(x.shape[0], -1).numpy()
    y = y.numpy()

    out = ann(x.T)
    loss = loss_fn.backward(out, y)
    ann.backward(loss)
    ann.update_params(lr)

    running_loss += loss_fn.item()
    total += y.shape[0]
    correct += (sigmoid(out.T).argmax(axis=1) == y).sum()

    if i % 250 == 0:
      print(f'Iter: {i} - Loss: {running_loss / i}')
  train_loss.append(running_loss / len(train_loader))
  train_acc.append(correct / total)

  running_loss = 0.
  total = 0.
  correct = 0
  for i, (x, y) in enumerate(tqdm(test_loader), 1):
    x = x.reshape(x.shape[0], -1).numpy()
    y = y.numpy()

    out = ann(x.T)
    loss = loss_fn(out, y)

    running_loss += loss
    total += y.shape[0]
    correct += (sigmoid(out.T).argmax(axis=1) == y).sum()
  val_loss.append(running_loss / len(test_loader))
  val_acc.append(correct / total)

  print(f'Epoch: {epoch+1} - Loss: {train_loss[-1]} - Accuracy {train_acc[-1]} - Val Loss: {val_loss[-1]} - Val Accuracy: {val_acc[-1]}')
# For 10th epoch:
#Epoch: 10 - Loss: 0.1848173206776424 - Accuracy 0.9755166666666667 - Val Loss: 0.1995236210747004 - Val Accuracy: 0.971

#CHECKING ACCURACY ON TEST SET
total = 0.
correct = 0.
preds = []
true = []
for x, y in tqdm(test_loader):
  x = x.reshape(x.shape[0], -1).numpy()
  y = y.numpy()

  out = ann(x.T)
  total += y.shape[0]
  preds.append(sigmoid(out.T).argmax(axis=1))
  true.append(y)
  correct += (sigmoid(out.T).argmax(axis=1) == y).sum()
correct / total # 0.971

x = mnist_test.data.numpy()
x = x.reshape(x.shape[0], -1)
y = mnist_test.targets.numpy()
out = ann(x.T)
(sigmoid(out.T).argmax(axis=1) == y).sum() / len(x) # 0.9557
```

Comment: It is hard to help you, if you don't provide any code that could be copied and executed. How about creating a minimal example?

Comment: Hi, added full code